# Delphi. Sockets. Access denied on TIdHttp socket connection on one node/MAC address only. Betfair API

Tags: delphi, sockets, http, ssl, request

I suspect this is fairly simple and so no code will be helpful.

I am developing a Delphi non-interactive 'bot' login app.

The app logs in okay with any account and certificate/key pair (registered with the corresponding account) on any machine but my current development system.

i.e. The same executable, with the same account login credentials and SSL certificate and key file selected, runs on every system I try it on with a successful login, but fails to login on my dev system (Windows 8.1) with an Access Denied error (10013).

It has been doing this since I crashed the development IDE three days ago. I suspect it is either:

1. There is a socket at raw sockets level on the API server locked open to the MAC address on my dev system (in a WAIT_STATE)
2. The crash raised some kind of block or exclusion on my account non-interactively logging in because of fraud prevention security triggering and blocking the socket/port.

I doubt 2 since it is a standard non-interactive bot login process and it is a developer API and so failed socket connections are likely to be common.

I only make a few dozen login calls per development day at most.

Have I been locked out, or is it an open socket in WAIT_STATE for my specific MAC address ... or something else?

If I fail to close and free the TIdHttp connection, or the app crashes (along with the IDE) due to incorrect handling of the SSL, how long will a server normally persist the WAIT_STATE for a socket connection - and would it attempt to reallocate the same socket and port for the same MAC address.

I have not tried a different port number, nor an explicit socket number.

I have tried changing the dev system's IP address and using different Wi Fi connections through different providers. If it is a raw socket binding problem - it is not against IP address - I think.

The same executable from the build works on all systems apart from the dev system on which the crash occurred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried restarting that system? Maybe if you can describe the cause of the initial crash in the first place, it could help us understand what might be going on.

Comment: Also, try running it with administrative privileges.

Comment: I think that I did not release/Free the socket, and or did not free the HttpClient object correctly initially. I am now not sure as at the time I thought something else might be going on and I changed the code.

I have multiply restarted the system and released and renewed the IP address, assigned different IP addresses manually, and tried connecting from different WiFi nodes. This is why I think that the machine ethernet MAC address has to be the problem. It occurs to me now that I should try it with a cable and therefore the other non Wi Fi MAC in the system.

Answer (score 3):

10013 is `WSAEACCES`, which is described as follows:

[Windows Sockets Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx):

> WSAEACCES
>   10013
>
> Permission denied.
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for [sendto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148.aspx) without broadcast permission being set using [setsockopt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476.aspx)(SO_BROADCAST).
>
> Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550.aspx) function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later), another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by using the [SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc150667.aspx) option.

Assuming by `WAIT_STATE`, you actually mean `TIME_WAIT`, then Windows keeps a socket in `TIME_WAIT` for only 120 seconds by default.  That does not cause a `WSAEACCES` error, though.  An attempt to use an IP/Port that is in TIME_WAIT results in an `WSAEADDRINUSE` error instead.

Some other app has likely grabbed the IP/Port that your app wants to use.  If you have not rebooted your machine for 3 days, that app may still be holding the IP/Port.  A reboot should clear the error.

Comment: Thanks Remy for more information about the specific nature of the error. Yes.  I mean TIME_WAIT. Other documentation confirms what you say about the WSAEADDRINUSE error, and I am not getting that error. I have multiply restarted the system and released and renewed the IP address, assigned different IP addresses manually, and tried connecting from different WiFi nodes. This is why I think that the machine ethernet MAC address has to be the problem. The same build executable with the same socket options works on other systems, but I will try altering the socket options anyway.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MAC addresses.  Sockets are at the app level and don't use MACs, they use IPs.  MACs are used by the OS at a lower level of the networking subsystem.

Comment: There are some situations where sockets bind to MAC addresses at the raw sockets level. Some systems and programmers do this. 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/remote-client-mac-address-on-socket-descriptor-850092/

Comment: However, I thought that it it should be the IP address too. Changing that does not appear to help at all.

Comment: @user3098527: Sockets do not bind to MACs, and TCP/UDP have no concept of MACs. MACs are handled at a completely different layer. The code you link to queries that other layer for the MAC of a given IP, but that is being done separate from the original socket.

Comment: Okay. I have tired the other MAC on the machine and same problem, and Wireshark is also not listing any end to end connections to the remote server even for attempts. I am assuming now that the server has assigned a different IP address and that it has been blocked for the application key (unique number identifying the application to the endpoint API server) that IP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contacting us.

I believe this is a Windows environment issue as this error isn't one that's returned by the Betfair API.

You can find an article relating to this particular problem via http://www.thinglink.org/socket-error-10013-access-denied.php

Kind Regards,

Neil

Betfair Developer Program

Please note: To help BDP answer your query more efficiently, please open a new ticket for each new query you may have.

API 5.0 & API 6.0 will be retired on the 1st November 2014 at which point applications using these API's will no longer work.  Therefore, we recommend that you migrate to API-NG as soon as possible.